# create a composite and use it in other projects (GWT)

Tags: gwt, composite

I have an image gallery project that displays images one by one.
I want it to be a composite so that I can use it in other project.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `gwtdesigner` there is an option to do it from eclipse: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/wizards/gwt/library

But the normal way, is:

- create a normal GWT module with its `.gwt.xml` file, and remove the entry-point tag.
- include the stuff you want to share in it: java code into the `client` folder, assets into the `public` one, and server code into the `server` one.
- compile and package as a `.jar` file. IMPORTANT: you must pack your source files in it.
- Import the library in your other projects as you normally do.
- Finally, remember to include a line to inherit your library module in the `gwt.xml` of those gwt projects using your library.

Comment: I do not understand part one, (create a normal GWT ...)
Could you please explaine a bit more?

Comment: Yes, you have to create a new GWT project like you do normally (usind Eclipse plugin or webAppCreator). But your new module does not need any entry point (the code to execute when the GWT app starts) since it is just a library with java stuff. So edit the gwt.xml of the recent created project and remove the '<entry-point>' tag.

Comment: sorry for this,
but what should I do with my war folder and its contents?
They don't need to be in jar file?

Comment: You dont have to create a .war file but a .jar. Are you using maven? ant?

Comment: none of them. :(
I have some html files in war folder. Should I consider them in jar file or not?

Comment: although you can create a .jar file by hand, almost projects use maven or ant to produce it. A .jar file is just a .zip file, try to uncompress any .jar you are using to see its content. Basically if you create a .zip file with all the stuff in your src and in your bin file, and rename it to .jar it should work. You can use eclipse to create your jar, but the only think you have to consider is to include  your src content in the jar.

Comment: One more final question:
I have problem in last section of your guide.
Do I have to include an inherit tag to my jar project?
Or Just an entry-point tag?
In what format should be that? (entry-point)
reference to client folder or not?

thanks in advance

Comment: In your jar should be a .gwt.xml file. ie: `com.example.mywidget.MyWidget.gwt.xml`. In applications using this jar, you have to inherit that module  `<inherits name="com.example.mywidget.MyWidget" />`